# Alternatives to jQuery FlexBox?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-flexbox

Are there any good alternatives to jQuery FlexBox? I need the functionality to select from auto-suggest drop down list and input new values like on a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Autocomplete control from jQuery UI has emerged to be a useful alternative for my own purposes:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/dropdowngrid.htm
this will contain all functionality of grid.